# Adding argument decorator breaks azure functions

Tags: typescript, azure-functions, typegraphql

I'm using type-graphql with Azure Functions typescript, everything works except when I try to create input types, like so:

```
@ObjectType()
class Recipe {
  @Field(type => ID)
  id: string;

  @Field(type => [String])
  ingredients: string[]
}


@Resolver(of => Recipe)
class RecipeResolver {   
    @Query(returns => Recipe, { nullable: true })
    recipe(@Arg("title") title: string): Promise<Recipe | undefined> {
      return undefined
    }
}
```

@Arg("title") seems to be breaking azure functions, when it's in there I get the following error when I try to deploy and test the function locally:

> [error] Worker was unable to load function graphql: 'TypeError: Cannot
>   read property '0' of undefined'

Without the @Arg decorator it builds and runs fine, I also use decorators elsewhere in the code and it all works without issues.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Could you share your actual function code as well?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this error you simply need to specify the type of your argument.

```ts
    @ObjectType()
    class Recipe {
      @Field(type => ID)
      id: string;
    
      @Field(type => [String])
      ingredients: string[]
    }
    
    
    @Resolver(of => Recipe)
    class RecipeResolver {   
        @Query(returns => Recipe, { nullable: true })
        recipe(@Arg("title", () => String) title: string): Promise<Recipe | undefined> {
          return undefined
        }

        @Query(returns => Recipe, { nullable: true })
        recipeOptional(@Arg("title", () => String, { nullable: true }) title?: string): Promise<Recipe | undefined> {
          return undefined
        }
    }
```